# Каким образом можно реализовать вывод средств на счет телефона/карту?

Tags: php, android

Делаю онлайн-лотерею, у каждого пользователя есть виртуальный баланс, как можно выполнить их вывод на реальный счёт? Ничего в интернете не нашел

Comment: А откуда они будут выводится?

Comment: Поискать компании-посредники которые пополняют счёт. У них есть и SOAP и другие удобства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое это создать, что-то наподобие тикет системы. Пользователь оставляет заявку на вывод средств. Указывает желаемый метод вывода (QIWI, банковская карта) и свои данные. Например номер телефона для киви или номер карты для вывода на карту. Ну это примерно. Далее. Сохранять эту заявку в базе данных. А в админ панели какой-нибудь выводить для админов эти заявки, ну и уже в ручную переводить деньги пользователям. Самое главное такой ручной способ лишает проблемы с выводом несуществующих сумм, то есть будь у вас проблема в защите и пользователь смог накрутить себе денег, он их не выведет т.к. Админ перед переводом может смотреть догм действий, как он получил эту сумму.

Comment: Спасибо, а возможно реализовать автоматическое пополнение счёта?

Answer (score 1):

Я то же бы хотел из виртуальных денег получать реальные, но ЦБ против. 
Выплачивать на мобильники можно через http://sotplat.ru/ . Как принимать лучше посмотри у online казино (они то собаку съели на абузаустойчивости)